# Database python telegram bot MySQL

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, aiogram

How I make two parametres for check database

info = db.execute(f"SELECT * FROM 'storage_users' WHERE status = ? balance = ?", [status, balance])

Two WHERE parametres

Comment: You might want to add the information in the comment to Aditya Yadav's as an edit to the question. What is the `user` you refered to?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[UUID](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html)** as primary key and use *chat_id* or *user_id* for Where's condition. And please explain your question breifly so we can answer better

Comment: I have two meanings of status and balance. I need to find a line in the database where, status = user, and balance = some amount. And I want to compare precisely on these two parameters, so as not to make two lines: 
info = db.execute(f"SELECT * FROM 'storage_users' WHERE status = ? ", [status, balance])
records = info.fetchall()
for row in records: 
      balance = row[balance]
      print(balance)

Comment: What is the 'user' refers to?

Answer (score 0):

Just add **AND** between 2 WHERE conditions:

```
info = db.execute("SELECT * FROM 'storage_users' WHERE status = ? **AND** balance = ?", 
(status, balance))
```